# Self-hosted Bitrix24: Add entries to the CRM through the API

Tags: php, api, bitrix

I'm trying to modify parts of the CRM (like deals, leads etc) using the API.

It all works fine when I'm working in the Bitrix24 cloud, i.e. on my_site.bitrix24.com

But when I'm using an application on a self hosted site (bitrix.my-site.com) I don't receive the access_token in the OAuth process.

Btw, I'm following this guide:

https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/oauth/refreshing.php

Is there another way for dealing with the API in self hosted apps?

Thank you

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: There is no need for code in this case. The procedure is described on the page I linked. It's only work with URLs, code is only needed when you want to automate the process, so you don't need to copy & paste links and keys all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Bitrix. If you are using self hosted trial, Bitrix24 requires valid on premise license and neither REST nor current marketplace apps will work with a trial version.

Comment: probably a comment, not an answer